# How to get the caller event and dom element id

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function Hello(){
    var caller =  arguments.callee.caller;
    alert( caller );
}
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnHello" value="Hello" onclick="Hello()" />
```

How to get the button id from the the Hello function above with out passing the any argument in the Hello function

Comment: By the way, arguments.callee.caller is a reference to the function, if any, that called the current function. It is not implemented in all browsers, and has been deprecated by the ecma script guys for years.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

An event object is passed to the Hello function automatically. You need to receive it as an argument and then do some cross-platform work to grab the element. A JS framework will help you out here.

```
function Hello(e){
    var caller = e.target || e.srcElement;
    console.log( caller );
}
```

**EDIT**
+1 Andrew's comment below. Use addEventListener and attachEvent for best practice.

Comment: event object is passed only if it is used like btnid.onclick = function(e){ alert( e.target )}; But how to get the event object when we apply event as inline.

Comment: IIRC, you can get it by setting the `onlick` attribute to "Hello(event)".

Comment: Attach events with unobtrusive JavaScript rather than using an inline event handler, then you can use the event object passed to event callbacks.