# How to listen for user edits but not programmatic edits for textfield in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I added a listener to the `change` event on a [TextField](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.TextField). When the user changes the value in the text field, my listener gets control. This is great.

In some cases, I want to restore the old value in the listener. However, when I call the `setValue` method in the listener, the `change` event fires again. What is the best way to restore the old value programmatically without the event firing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set flag on `TextField` indicating that you change value programatically. Eg:

```
new Ext.form.TextField({
    renderTo: 'container',
    listeners: {
        change: function(sender, newValue, oldValue) {
            if (this.restoringValue) {
                return;
            }
            if (newValue == 'XXX') {
                this.restoringValue = true;
                this.setValue(oldValue);
                delete this.restoringValue;
            }
        }
    },
    value: 'XXX'
});
```

If you don't have any buffers or delays on change listener it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the event handler to look at the `caller` of the function. Based on that, drop out of the event handler.

See: [How to get the caller event and dom element id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945201/how-to-get-the-caller-event-and-dom-element-id)

Comment: Whether the event handler is invoked due to the user changing the field or due to the handler itself changing the field, I believe the `caller` is the same. In either case, the `caller` is an Ext JS function that calls the listeners of the `change` event.

Comment: Ok, then create a variable called "ignoreEvent". Set/clear it on your setValue and have the event ignore things if the flag is set.

Comment: I first tried `field.suspendEvents(false); field.setValue(value); field.resumeEvents();`, but this did not seem to prevent my handler from being re-invoked. So, I went with your suggestion to use a flag. I'd love to hear if anyone has insight on why the first approach did not work. Many thanks, Diodeus, for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

setRawValue( Object value ) : Object

Sets the field's raw value directly, bypassing value conversion, change detection, and validation.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-setRawValue

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to stop the check change event that is a property on the field that the checkChange event looks for. it's

**field.suspendCheckChange = true**

this is because the checkChange function that is fired by the setValue method is

```
checkChange: function() {
        var me = this,
            newVal, oldVal;

        if (!me.suspendCheckChange) {
            newVal = me.getValue();
            oldVal = me.lastValue;

            if (!me.isDestroyed && me.didValueChange(newVal, oldVal)) {
                me.lastValue = newVal;
                me.fireEvent('change', me, newVal, oldVal);
                me.onChange(newVal, oldVal);
            }
        }
    },
```

this is in 5.1, not sure if it's earlier versions..

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/source/Field.html#Ext-form-field-Field-method-checkChange